# Wi-Fi problems with HP laptop

Tags: wireless

I recently installed 14.04 LTS on my HP 2000-369WM Notebook PC. I think I need drivers to get my wifi to work. Can you help? Specifically, I need the text that you enter into the terminal that tells you what Wi-Fi hardware your computer has. I can then download the necessary drivers. I found it once before but have been unable to since.

Comment: I hope it helps -https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless.html

Comment: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` shows all the necessary device info

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy31. That seems to have done the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the command you are looking for:

```
lspci
```

(or, better yet, `lspci | grep --ignore-case Network`)